# Remove last instance of \ in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, text-processing

I would like to strip, up to last instance of `\`, in a text file. The `\` is in a floating position and different occurrences.

I would like to implement this from a Unix command line and put it into a shell script. This is for windows 10 v20H2 x86 running J.P. Software 4nt, tcc, tccle. I also have implement MKS toolkit for the unix based commands

ex. I use the following from the cmd prompt to create the input text raw file:

```
set dr=d:\!Mp3_A-Z
echo Reading All Folders in Drive %dr...
dir/b /s %dr"\"*.mp3 > %destfolder\!geb3raw.lst
```

There are over 100,000 lines in the input txt file.

ex: input from raw txt file

```
D:\!Mp3_A-Z\!AB^5117\ABBA (Rock 061619)\ABBA - Dancing Queen '128k '03_52.mp3
D:\!Mp3_A-Z\!AB^5117\!Band - RJG (Rock 061519)\Nightsoil (1972 Beckford St Tapes) 06 - Smile Away '128k '04_40.mp3
```

output:

```
ABBA - Dancing Queen '128k '03_52.mp3
Nightsoil (1972 Beckford St Tapes) 06 - Smile Away '128k '04_40.mp3
```

Comment: I understand that you want the file name only.  This can be done on Linux with command `basename`.  However you ask for a unix command, but the data you provide is Windows format.  The `\\` has a different meaning on unix than on Windows.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have replaced your batch file reference and [[tag:batch-file]] tag, as you specifically mentioned "unix cmd line", with the [[tag:shell]] tag and term shell script. If you meant something different please review your tags and clarify your question, before it is closed. Please also take the [tour], and read through all of the pages of [ask], to understand why your code request, is considered as off topic here, and shoulld not be answered.

Comment: Typically, a Unix emulator package replaces such commands as `find` which in `Windows` means "locate a string within a file" with its `Unix` meaning, "find a file". The `Windows`  command to do what you appear to want to do  (generate a file of the filenames alone, without the path) would be `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%destfolder%\!geb3raw.lst") do echo %%~nxb >>newfilename.txt` noting that `%destfolder%`, not `%destfolder` is resolved to "the value of the variable `destfolder` and that `>>` appends to any existing file, so you'd need to delete that destination file first.

Comment: In Unix terminology, what you seem to want is the 'base name' of the file — the last component of the pathname for the file.  There is a Unix `basename` command that would provide the output you wanted if the file names matched Unix conventions.  I don't know whether the command is available in your environment, nor whether it will deal with backslashes instead of slashes in the file names.  Try it — it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/.*\\//' myfile.txt
```

This replaces everything up to and including a backslash with nothing.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Modified with input > output. sed 's/.*\\//' rawfile.txt > stripped.txt